# problem installing react-redux in create-react-app project

Tags: reactjs, npm, redux, react-redux, create-react-app

To familiarize myself with Redux for a side job, I tried creating a project with the create-react-app redux template, and ran into this error:

```
Installing template dependencies using npm...
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: my-app@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.3 || ^17" from react-redux@7.2.6
npm ERR! node_modules/react-redux
npm ERR!   react-redux@"^7.2.3" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/itsme/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/itsme/.npm/_logs/2022-03-30T07_04_21_133Z-debug-0.log
`npm install --no-audit --save @reduxjs/toolkit@^1.5.1 @testing-library/jest-dom@^4.2.4 @testing-library/react@^9.3.2 @testing-library/user-event@^7.1.2 react-redux@^7.2.3` failed
```

I thought the issue might be emanating from the template, so I created a vanilla create-react-app project, and then tried installing react-redux manually, but got the same error. Running the --force and --legacy-peer-deps commands don't have any effect. My Node (v16.14.2) and npm (8.5.5) versions are up-to-date. Can anyone tell me what's going on here?

Comment: can you tell me what the exact command you used for `redux template`

Comment: @DharmikPatel command used was `npx create-react-app my-app --template redux`

Answer (score 0):

First write

```
npm config set legacy-peer-deps true
```

and then **install your package.**